# Azure AD Users enrolled in Password Hash Synchronization and Pass through Authentication

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

Is there any attribute or api to identify about whether a user is enrolled in the Password Hash Synchronization or Pass through Authentication in Azure Active directory

Answer (score 1):

As per this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/tshoot-connect-password-hash-synchronization#understand-the-results-of-the-troubleshooting-task) ,

- Only Azure AD Connect versions 1.1.614.0 and later support the troubleshooting task.
- Only Azure AD Connect versions 1.1.524.0 and later support the 'Invoke-ADSyncDiagnostics' cmdlet.

With the help of below command , we can find out whether `Password Hash Synchronization` is enabled for the Azure AD Users

```cs
Invoke-ADSyncDiagnostics -PasswordSync
```